# React.js: How to properly append multiple items to an array state using its use-state hook setter?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, use-state, object-literal, spread-expression

My component has a state that should store an array of objects. I initialized it to be empty.

```
    const [tableDataSource, setTableDataSource] = useState([])
```

After a couple successful fetching and reorganizing of fetch results, *one or more* object literals should be appended to the **tableDataSource** state. Desired output should be

```
[
    {
        key: 1,
        key2: 'sample string value',
        key3: false,
    },
    {
        key: 'sample string value',
        key2: true,
    }
]
```

My current fetch result is another array containing **2** object literals. I tried to append all items from this array to the state setter.

```
    let dataSource = generateRows(showCompletedItems, fetchResult);
```

The code above reorganizes the fetch results into desired output. I logged **dataSource** in the console and verified if it is an Array object and it returned **true**.

Somewhere inside the component declaration I also have a **useEffect** that logs the current **tableDataSource** to output the changes.

```
    console.log('TABLE DATA SOURCE >>>>', tableDataSource, typeof tableDataSource);
```

I have a difficult time appending the array items into the state array using its setter. I tried Approach # 1:

```
    setTableDataSource(dataSource);
```

The console does not log anything.

Approach # 2:

```
    setTableDataSource((tableDataSource) => [...tableDataSource, dataSource])
```

Returns a nested array as shown below:

```
    [[{...},{...}]]
```

If I used Approach # 2 and initialized the component state like this:

```
    const [tableDataSource, setTableDataSource] = useState([{}])
```

Result:

```
    [{}, [{...}, {...}]]
```

Approach # 3 does not log anything like the first one

```
    setTableDataSource((tableDataSource) => [...tableDataSource, ...dataSource])
```

Answer (score 6):

Figured it out.

```
setArrayOfObjects((currentObjects) => currentObjects.concat([ ...anotherArrayOfObjects]))
```

I hope this very specific problem will help others. It was very annoying, it took me hours to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Set.

```
setTableDataSource((tableDataSource) => [... new Set([...tableDataSource, ...dataSource])])
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set